# Div's height set to 0 after masonry applying

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have div content with many products and is set

```
div#content{
       margin-top:20px;
       width: 560px;
       min-height: 700px;
       float:right;
}
```

but after applying masonry (jquery plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/) like this:

```
   $('#content').masonry({
      columnWidth: 275,
      itemSelector: '.produkt'
   }).imagesLoaded(function() {
      $('#content').masonry('reload');
   });
```

is div#content's height set to 0...

Can anybody help me with it, please?

Thanks

Comment: jquery plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Could you show a demo or JSFiddle? Are you using V2?

Comment: demo is here: www.marygate.cz/beta sorry, only in czech language, but code is in english

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it, other than setting the height attribute (or do it with CSS) of the image, is to wrap your masonry code in window load, instead of document ready.

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $('#content').masonry({
        columnWidth: 275,
        itemSelector: '.produkt',
        animate: true
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to initiate the masonry again (after a couple of calculations) in which the `columnWidth` was the only option needed. This had to be done in a `$(window).load` function indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Set the min-height on the items (with .produkt class)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the imagesLoaded Plugin isn't working. Without the images loaded, Masonry assumes the container is empty and sets the height to 0. What does the JS console tell you?

Comment: It shows this... TypeError: $(...).masonry(...).imagesLoaded is not a function

Comment: You definitely have the syntax down, are you sure you've included the imagesLoaded Plugin in the <head>? Bear in mind that masonry no longer comes with it, you have to download it from https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: Thanks, i dont know jquery good, i edited final resolution only... i've download it, include it in head, but now the console says `no such method 'reload' for masonry instance`

Comment: If I'm being honest, version 2 of Masonry came with a lot of trouble for me, especially with this. If you set the height of the image with CSS, you won't need the imagesLoaded at all. However, apparrently, the new masonry fixes this (it was a bug). Is your masonry script recent?

Comment: It was downloaded from official site, so it should be new. Now i've edited it and i dont have imageLoad there... But still is height 0...

Comment: I think i know why is this happened.. I use masonry on every page even if there was any images... It definitely be the problem :)

Comment: See my other answer below :)

Comment: It's definitely the image height. It works fine for me once you hit F5, but not on the first try because they images haven't been cached yet. Setting the height of the image will work, or calling the masonry code onload.

Answer (score -3):

Try setting this to div#content

```
overflow: auto;
```